# Column/SingleChildScrollView not scrolling

Tags: flutter, scroll, flutter-layout, rendering

I'm learning flutter to make an app. Here I'm trying to make a page to show the full post. The problem is that the page isn't scrolling as a single unit.

```
class SinglePostPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Post? post;
  const SinglePostPage({Key? key, this.post}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SinglePostPage> createState() => _SinglePostPageState();
}

class _SinglePostPageState extends State<SinglePostPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 22.5),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 6),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    const BackButton(),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            showDialog(...);
                          },
                          child: CircleAvatar(...),
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.4),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  showDialog(...);
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                  widget.post!.author[0].profileName,
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 4),
                              Text(
                                showTimeAgo(widget.post!.postTime).toString(),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    PopupMenuButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                      itemBuilder: (context) => [...],
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 9, 12, 3),
    // when the text is longer than the screen height it showed RenderFlex overflowed error so I put constraints. how to show it full and make this scroll
                  constraints: BoxConstraints( 
                      maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.54,
                      minHeight: 50),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Text(
                      widget.post!.postText,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    if (widget.post!.postMedia.isNotEmpty)
                      CarouselSlider.builder(...),
                    const SizedBox(height: 4.5),
                    if (widget.post!.postMedia.length > 1)
                      buildDotIndicator(widget.post!.postMedia),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            // post reactions row
          ),
          CommentBodyWidget(
            postId: widget.post!.postId,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I looked up for other answers and tried wrapping it with SingleChildScrollView, but it didn't work , and ListView with `shrinkWrap: true` also gave 'Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget' error.

CommentBodyWidget has a listview builder. It's scrolling on its own but the widget above isn't scrolling along with it.

How can I show this whole page and scroll together without having to limit the long post in a constrained container? Please help.

Comment: Do you want separate scroll for Listview, or it will scrollable as full screen.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh The whole page to scroll as single page. The full text and comments Listview too. I remember you helped me with previous error in model. Very grateful to see you again...

Answer (score 4):

In order for the `SingleChildScrollView` to work, its parent's height should be defined.
You can achieve this by wrapping the `SingleChildScrollView` in a `Container/SizedBox` with defined height, or by wrapping it with the `Expanded` widget.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap  `body` `Column` with `SingleChildScrollView` and  use `shrinkWrap: true,` and use `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),`. This will solve the issue.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        //...

        ListView.builder(
          itemCount: itemlength,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Text("item $index");
          },
        ),

        /// instead of listView
        ...List.generate(itemlength, (index) => Text("itemWidget"))
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

But I will encourage you to check [`CustomScrollView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html).

Comment: I'm getting this error now bro: 
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Comment: and regarding commentbodywidget, I'm using it to show comments in the separate all comments page too, so I can't use neverscrollablephysics there. If it must be done I'll have to make another copy of the widget in this file to use it here only. I can go with that also as long as I get the scroll behaviour right...

Comment: Can you provide a full sample widget that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: could you please help me with this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71778258/flutter-stateful-widget-page-not-updating

Answer (score 0):

Pass `SingleChildScrollView` as body of your scaffold. Also `shrinkwrap: true` for the ListView is recommended so that it only takes up as much space as required, which will avoid unbounded height errors.

So instead of

```
...
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Container(
...
```

Do this

```
...
Widget build(BuildContext context) 
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(...
```

Comment: I'm getting error bro... 
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.

These invalid constraints were provided to RenderFlex's layout() function by the following function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout
package:flutter/…/rendering/proxy_box.dart:277

The offending constraints were: BoxConstraints(w=436.4, h=Infinity)
The relevant error-causing widget was
Container

Comment: @rawm I made a mistake that outer Container wasn't necessary, removing it helps runs the app without any error. However I do not have your other classes so my screen is almost empty with no data, so you need to test that yourself now. I have edited my initial answer. Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use CustomScrollView.

Try this:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverFillRemaining(
      hasScrollBody: false,
      child: Column("""HERE PUT YOUR CODE""")
    )]
),
```

Comment: without 'hasScrollBody: false' it didn't make any difference. After I added it I got this error:
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════

The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.

Calculating the intrinsic dimensions would require instantiating every child of the viewport, which defeats the point of viewports being lazy.

Comment: Can you try this?  CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverFillRemaining(
      hasScrollBody: false,
      child: Text(
                      widget.post!.postText,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
    )])
);

Comment: yes I did. I got the error when i used `hasScrollBody: false`, and without adding that it didn't make any difference in scroll behaviour